# How to write query in the following case?

Tags: sql

I have the following table.  How do I query
Table Team is as follows:

```
    ID,Name,City,League
    1,Name1,City1, A
    2,Name2,City1, B
```

Comment: what will your desired result look like?

Comment: Why did you change this question so dramatically? It doesn't make any sense in context of the answers you got below.  If you want to ask a different question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to get a `COUNT(DISTINCT League)` per city, and compare that number to the total number of leagues `COUNT(DISTINCT League)` across the whole table.

```
SELECT
  City,
  COUNT(DISTINCT League) AS numleagues
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY City
/* Only cities which have the same number of distinct leagues as the total number of distinct leagues */
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT League) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT League) FROM yourtable)
```

[Here it is in action in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f67d9/1)

Answer (score 0):

All cities for which there does not exist a League which is not in the list of Leagues associated with the city:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Teams T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Teams T2 WHERE League NOT IN 
      (SELECT League FROM Teams T3 WHERE T3.City = T1.City))
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost exactly as you worded it in English, but with a twist... You want all cities that have a Name in all leagues, or to rephrase, you want all Cities where there does not exist a League that does not have a name in it from that city.;..

```
  Select Distinct City From Table t
  Where Not Exists
    (Select Distinct League From Table L
     Where Not Exists 
         (Select * From Table
          Where City = t.City
             And League = L.League 
             And Name Not in 
                  (Select distinct Name from table 
                   Where City = t.City) ))
```