# Combine 2 SQL SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

** Evidently some people think my question is not worthy of their time. I whole heartedly appologise for this. However, rather than down voting why not use that time to do something positive and at least tell me what info you would require to make this not be a cr@p question in your eyes. **

I have a list of staff in table `tblMembers` and a list of clients in table `tblClients`.

One person may have several client.

The staff member associated with a client is identified by `staffId` against the client record.

Each staff member has a category Id for the type of clients they have `catId`.

***I need to find all of the staff for a given client type and then sort them by the number of clients they have. Staff members without any clients should show a result of 0 rather than not showing.***

A simplified table structure would be:

`tblMembers`:

```
Id | catId
```

`tblClients`:

```
Id | staffId
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @poiluska All sort but evidently dont know what I'm doing. Im not sure how that impacts upon the validity of my question though. An answer based on the simplicity of my table structure above would be enough to help me figure out the actual real world situation that I have. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use a JOIN to get data from both tables, and a GROUP BY to summarize the number of clients per staff member.  Look back through your class notes to the day(s) when those subjects were covered.

Comment: My apologies if you're not a student looking for an answer to a homework exercise and I confused you with one.  Since there's no SQL shown in your question, I think it's not unreasonable to conclude that you were looking for a place to begin (which is with a JOIN and GROUP BY) rather than trying to refine some code you had already written.  Students looking for answers to assignments without putting in any effort of their own is becoming an issue here at Stackoverflow.  FYI, I am not either of the downvoters, or the vote-to-close on this question.

Comment: @Phil: In response to your edit -- 1) you haven't shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself, so it's impossible to have any idea what you've tried or what level of knowledge you have about SQL and 2) you haven't stated *specifically* where your problem is (from reading some of your other comments it appears you know how to JOIN the tables but not how to accomplish the inclusion of the staff without any clients).  If your question had read "Here's my SQL so far, but it misses out the staff without any clients" you wouldn't have had the poor reception you did.

Comment: @LarryLustig In effect we're all "students" studying our subjects; and long may I be studying these subjects (luckily work seem to pay me aswell!). Simple questions are often the best. I do agree with you that the OPer should have atleast let us see their attempt at the script. I suspect different people will use SO in different ways (I sometimes post questions I know will be down-voted just to fish for an opinion on an aspect of some code)

Comment: @Larry Lustig I appreciate the case of people not apparently trying to solve things before posting here. But maybe thats because they just dont know where to start. Not everyone is just plain lazy. Helpful pointers are required, not arrogant remarks. In terms of why I posted what I did... Well I didnt want to confuse things by posting my own useless solution and inadvertantly throw people off track. Hence I gave a simplified breakdown, and minimalist table example. I was trying to make it easier for everyone as I appreciate those who take the time to help me out.

Comment: Well, it was the failure to show how far you got that (almost certainly, I can't speak for the folks who gave you those votes) led to the downvotes and the vote to close.  This appeared to me to be a "do my homework for me" question — I did jump to that conclusion and I'll try to be more careful about that in the future.  But at least three people (the two downvoters and myself) and probably more had the same response to your question.

Comment: @LarryLustig don't forget the randomness of views and its impact on voting. e.g. [This problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12791949/119477) that you answered  didn't garner any downvotes and I wouldn't call it a better question. Personally I rarely care what the OP has tried. Instead I prefer questions with sample data and desired output

Comment: @Conrad Frix I agree that question is fooked up. Also, Larry's response isnt very helpful as it doesnt really explain anything. However, thats just my view and I cant see any value in degrading it. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.Id 'Member Id', ISNULL(c.StaffCount, 0) 'StuffCount'
FROM tblMembers m
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT staffId, COUNT(staffId) 'StaffCount'
    FROM tblClients
    GROUP BY staffId
) c ON m.Id = c.staffId
WHERE m.Cat = 'Some Id'
ORDER BY StuffCount
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. With a little tinkering to fit my real world scenario it appears to fit the job perfectly. Thanks for your time and help. Its greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its fairly simple to do a join/group and count

```
SELECT
   s.id,
   s.catid,
   COUNT(c.id)
FROM 
   tblMembers s
   LEFT JOIN tblClients  c
   ON s.id = c.staffid
WHERE
   s.catid = @catID
GROUP BY 
  s.id,
  s.catid
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(c.id) desc
```

However the one tricky bit is

> show a result of 0 rather than not showing.

To do this you need to do a left join to make sure they show even if there are no matching records and you need to make sure to count a field on the table on the Right side of the join. Otherwise you'd get a count of 1

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d76d/1)

Comment: Thanks for the input, the 0 count is the bit that is proving to be the real issue for me. Without it, my solution is as good as useless.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I correctly understood your case.
Try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.ID, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   MEMBERS T1 
       INNER JOIN CLIENTS T2 
               ON T1.ID = T2.STAFFID 
WHERE  T1.CATID = 2 
GROUP  BY T1.ID 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
                0 
FROM   MEMBERS 
WHERE  CATID != 2
```

A working sample is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c44ee/4).

Comment: I posted a reply but its not saved. Oh well to be concise, I basically said I went with Mahmood Gamals response purely because I saw it first. When I have time I'll try yours as Im interested to see which method would run quickest. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select tblMembers.id, count(tblClient.id)
from tblMembers left join tblCLient on staffId = tblMembers.id
where tblMembers.catId = ??
group by tblMembers.id
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Vuurents, Im guessing this wouldnt return 0 values though??

Comment: yes it will. The left join makes sure all tblMembers are left in the resultset, and the count on the tblClient.Id gives 0 because for those tblMembers the tblClient.id will have a NULL value. try it out.